# Google analytics api v4 custom report

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm trying to automatise the Google analytics report of our app websites, something like 55 or so.

What I need is:

```
avg time
users new/returning
direct/referral/search
users per day (based on 1st of the month to the last day)
```

I'm using the guide from Google

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php

my function for the report is something like this:

```
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "XXXX";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("2019-05-01");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("2019-05-31");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  $users = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $users->setExpression("ga:users");
  $users->setAlias("users");

  $newSessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $newSessions->setExpression("ga:percentNewSessions");
  $newSessions->setAlias("newSessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions,$users,$newSessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```

Of course is not the definitely one I'm just experimenting with some metrics.

I was trying to get back the users per day like this

```
  $monthusers = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $monthusers->setExpression("ga:30dayUsers");
  $monthusers->setAlias("monthusers");
```

and then in the request

```
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions,$users,$newSessions,$monthusers));
```

but it throw a 500 error, any idea on how to get back the users per day? and based on the:

```
$dateRange->setStartDate("2019-05-01");
$dateRange->setEndDate("2019-05-31");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per mentioned in the [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer for the metric "ga:30dayUsers"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_30dayusers):

> At least one of ga:nthDay, ga:date, or ga:day must be specified as a
>   dimension to query this metric.

You could use the `ga:day` dimension into your report request to solve the issue:

```
$day = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$day->setName("ga:day");

$request->setDimensions(array($day));
```

Comment: it works without needs to use the `ga:30dayUsers`, it return the users for each day with `ga:users` and all the other metrics with the `dimension`  added to the `$request`, I'll check more into it, where can I find the `Classes` and the other method like `setDimensions` ?

Comment: You can find samples here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples